# Is there a way to get all User Stories for some project by tag using Rally Rest API?

Tags: java, rest, rally

Is there a way in Rally to get all User Stories for some project by tag using Rally Rest API ? 
I have found a way to [retrieve user stories by iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738819/fetch-user-stories-by-iteration-using-rally-api), and I need to get all User Stories independent from Iteration, though I can iterate through all stories and sort them by tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add a query filter for tags:

```
QueryRequest taggedStoryRequest = new QueryRequest("hierarchicalrequirement");
taggedStoryRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Tags.Name", "contains", "My Tag"));
QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(taggedStoryRequest);
```